# How to keep the text drawn in Graphics g after repaint()

Tags: java

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel {

int Mouse_x = 0, Mouse_y = 0;

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    this.setOpaque(true);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g2.drawString(Mouse_x + "," + Mouse_y, Mouse_x, Mouse_y);
}
}
```

How I can save this text on frame and when needed clear all frame.
Example:
[image]

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are asking. please be more specific as to what is currently happening versus what you want to happen.

Comment: ValekHalfHeart, added screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Mouse for coordinates?  you can use Mouse Listener and use method mouseClicked  ( after mouse click it will make x,y coordinates with your string.)

```
public void createDot(int x, int y){
   g.drawString(Mouse_x + "," + Mouse_y, x, y);
}
```

You have to add `addMouseListener(this);`  and implement its methods. I wrote just mouseClicked method

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();

    createDot(x,y);

}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

}
```

and your GUI create in another Method: e.g.

```
public static void createGUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
    JComponent component = new Drawing();
    component.setOpaque(true);
    frame.add(component);
    frame.setSize(600,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

then run in in main method:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
            createGUI();
        }
```

Comment: I add MouseAdapter, thanks I solved my problem